# CTE top - order by clause is not always working

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression, derived-table

I have the following T-SQL statement:

```
;WITH DataSource ([ColumnA]) AS
(
    SELECT TOP 100 [ColumnA] 
    FROM [dbo].[TEST] 
    WHERE [ColumnB] = 40 
    ORDER BY [ColumnC] DESC
)
SELECT [ColumnA]
      ,COUNT([ColumnA])
FROM DataSource
GROUP BY [ColumnA]
```

It is simply not returing the same result. I can not understand way, but some time the T-SQL statement in the CTE is not returning the correct values are because of this different results is produce, not each time, but sometimes (to be more accurate I am getting three different results).

If I excute only the following statement:

```
SELECT TOP 100 [ColumnA] 
FROM [dbo].[TEST] 
WHERE [ColumnB] = 40 
ORDER BY [ColumnC] DESC
```

I am getting the same results each time. And if I am using derived table there is no problems too:

```
SELECT [ColumnA]
      ,COUNT([ColumnA])
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 100 [ColumnA] 
    FROM [dbo].[TEST] 
    WHERE [ColumnB] = 40 
    ORDER BY [ColumnC] DESC

) DataSource
GROUP BY [ColumnA]
```

Can anyone explaing why the CTE is not returning the correct results each time?

Comment: Is `ColumnC` unique? If not you will need to add a guaranteed unique column(s) to the `ORDER BY` to act as a tie breaker to ensure deterministic results.

Comment: In what way are the results wrong? Is it returning (up to) 100 rows where `ColumnB` equals 40 and the `ColumnC` values are as low as possible? Because that's all it guarantees to do.

Comment: @MartinSmith, no it is not unique. Does make sense.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes, you right - what the hell I was thinking about...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As  `Martin Smith` pointed in his comment:

> Is ColumnC unique? If not you will need to add a guaranteed unique
>   column(s) to the ORDER BY to act as a tie breaker to ensure
>   deterministic results.

There is nothing wrong with the `CTE` itself - the issue is I am not sorting by `unique` column.

Answer (score 0):

An ORDER BY is not allowed inside the CTE construct. Please see the remarks section here: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx).  Provide the order by as part of the CTE_QUERY_DEFINITION.  I am surprised SQL server even let you run it.

Comment: From your link: `ORDER BY (except when a TOP clause is specified)`

Comment: Wow I completely missed your TOP statement.  My apologies.  Did you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924940/sql-cte-and-order-by-affecting-result-set