# Order By Not Working Using "WITH" Clause

Tags: sql, firebird

I am usung Firebird database.

I have below SQL, which is concatenating the ShortCode column data, but without ordering as per the ORDER_NUMBER column in ABC table in "WITH" clause.

```
With TBL_SHORT_CODE (SHORT_CODE, FK_KEY) As 
(
SELECT Distinct(XYZ.SHORT_CODE) As SHORT_CODE, ABC.FK_KEY 
From ABC Join XYZ On ABC.PK_KEY = XYZ.FK_KEY
where XYZ.FK_KEY = '{009DA0F8-51EE-4207-86A6-7E18F96B983A}' And ABC.STATUS_CODE = 1
Order By ABC.ORDER_NUMBER
)


SELECT LIST(Distinct(TBL_SHORT_CODE.SHORT_CODE), '' ), ABC.FK_BOM
From ABC 
Join XYZ ON ABC.FK_KEY = XYZ.PK_KEY 
Join TBL_SHORT_CODE On TBL_SHORT_CODE.FK_KEY = ABC.FK_KEY
where ABC.FK_BOM = '{009DA0F8-51EE-4207-86A6-7E18F96B983A}' And ABC.STATUS_CODE = 1
Group By ABC.FK_BOM
```

Thanks In Advance.

With Best Regards.

Vishal

Comment: Your ORDER BY is "too early" or meaningless to the query processor

Comment: only the recursive element of a common table expression may include an order by expression, or, when using `TOP` see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924940/sql-cte-and-order-by-affecting-result-set

Comment: @ric in Firebird you can put an order by in a with clause, the effects are just not guaranteed (the sort might be retained when no other steps in the query plan cause a sort). In this case, the presence of a list(distinct ...), group by on an unrelated field and several joins all might cause a query plan that causes a sort that will remove the effect of the sort in the with.

Comment: `distinct` is ***NOT*** a function! `distinct Distinct(XYZ.SHORT_CODE) As SHORT_CODE, ABC.FK_KEY` is the same as `Distinct XYZ.SHORT_CODE As SHORT_CODE, ABC.FK_KEY`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got problem solved in Firebird yahoo group.

SQL:

```
EXECUTE BLOCK RETURNS (SHORT_CODES VARCHAR(2000), FK_BOM INTEGER
AS 
DECLARE VARIABLE SHORT_CODE1 VARCHAR(2000);
DECLARE VARIABLE FK_BOM2 INTEGER;
DECLARE VARIABLE DUMMY INTEGER;
BEGIN
    FK_BOM = NULL;
    FOR With TBL_SHORT_CODE (SHORT_CODE, FK_KEY, ORDER_NUMBER) As 
        (SELECT XYZ.SHORT_CODE, ABC.FK_KEY, min(ABC.ORDER_NUMBER)
        From ABC Join XYZ On ABC.PK_KEY = XYZ.FK_KEY
        where XYZ.FK_KEY = '{009DA0F8-51EE-4207-86A6-7E18F96B983A}' And ABC.STATUS_CODE = 1
        group by 1, 2)

    SELECT ABC.FK_BOM, tsc.SHORT_CODE, min(tsc.ORDER_NUMBER)
    From ABC 
    Join XYZ ON ABC.FK_KEY = XYZ.PK_KEY 
    Join TBL_SHORT_CODE tsc On tsc.FK_KEY = ABC.FK_KEY
    where ABC.FK_BOM = '{009DA0F 8-51EE-4207-86A6-7E18F96B983A}' And ABC.STATUS_CODE = 1
    Group By 1, 2
    ORDER BY 1, 3
    into :FK_BOM2, :SHORT_CODE1, :DUMMY do
    begin
        if (FK_BOM2 > FK_BOM) then
            suspend;
        if (FK_BOM2 is distinct from FK_BOM) then
        begin
            FK_BOM = FK_BOM2;
            SHORT_CODES = '';
        end
        SHORT_CODES = SHORT_CODES || SHORT_CODE1;
    end
    suspend;
end
```

Answer (score 2):

ORDER BY does not function in a common table expression, and your join to TBL_SHORT_CODE would gain no benefit from it anyway. If your ordering is simply to order the output, then alter your script to order in your final query:

```
With TBL_SHORT_CODE (SHORT_CODE, FK_KEY) As 
(
SELECT XYZ.SHORT_CODE As SHORT_CODE, ABC.FK_KEY
From ABC Join XYZ On ABC.PK_KEY = XYZ.FK_KEY
where XYZ.FK_KEY = '{009DA0F8-51EE-4207-86A6-7E18F96B983A}' And ABC.STATUS_CODE = 1
GROUP BY XYZ.SHORT_CODE, ABC.FK_KEY
)


SELECT LIST(Distinct(TBL_SHORT_CODE.SHORT_CODE), '' ), ABC.FK_BOM
From ABC 
Join XYZ ON ABC.FK_KEY = XYZ.PK_KEY 
Join TBL_SHORT_CODE On TBL_SHORT_CODE.FK_KEY = ABC.FK_KEY
where ABC.FK_BOM = '{009DA0F8-51EE-4207-86A6-7E18F96B983A}' And     ABC.STATUS_CODE = 1
Group By ABC.FK_BOM
```

Comment: If I use Order By ABC.ORDER_NUMBER in main SQL then I get five records that is the reason I was trying in WITH clause. I need to get only one record with concatenation of all values of Short_Code field. Any suggestion ?

Comment: Use a GROUP BY to group all your duplicates up before returning your TBL_SHORT_CODE common table expression. See my edit.

Comment: The issue is ORDER_NUMBER contains 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 values. That's why I need to avoid ORDER_NUMBER column in Group By clause.

Comment: You can remove it entirely from your GROUP BY clause. See my prior edit.

Comment: If I remove then it gives an error, "Invalid expression in the ORDER BY clause (not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause)".

Comment: You are attempting to order by a column which does not exist. Do you still require to order by the ORDER_NUMBER field? If not, remove it.

Comment: That's why I tried using Order By in WITH clause. I need to to get Short_Code values but as per ORDER_NUMBER field in Ascending order.

Comment: In an earlier comment you said that without grouping you would return multiple fields which you didn't want. Now you require multiple fields sorted by ORDER_NUMBER. Could you clarify what you require please? Those two requirements are mutually exclusive.

Comment: For your clarification, A belongs to 10, B -> 20, C -> 30, D -> 40 and E -> 50. Then I need to get the result as: ABCDE, FK_BOM as one record.

Answer (score 0):

Try following,

```
with TBL_SHORT_CODE (SHORT_CODE, FK_KEY, FK_BOM, ORDER_NUMBER) As 
(
     SELECT Distinct(XYZ.SHORT_CODE) As SHORT_CODE
          , ABC.FK_KEY, ABC.FK_BOM, ABC.ORDER_NUMBER
       From ABC Join XYZ On ABC.PK_KEY = XYZ.FK_KEY
      where XYZ.FK_KEY = '{009DA0F8-51EE-4207-86A6-7E18F96B983A}'
        And ABC.STATUS_CODE = 1
)


SELECT LIST(Distinct(TBL_SHORT_CODE.SHORT_CODE), '' ), A.FK_BOM
  From TBL_SHORT_CODE A
 where A.FK_BOM = '{009DA0F8-51EE-4207-86A6-7E18F96B983A}'
   And ABC.STATUS_CODE = 1
 Group By A.FK_BOM
 ORDER BY TBL_SHORT_CODE.ORDER_NUMBER
```

Comment: If I remove then it gives an error, "Invalid expression in the ORDER BY clause (not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause)".